# Send Number Using HTML Form to Laravel

Tags: php, html, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am curious on how laravel validates number, i had this code:

```
$valid = \Validator::make(['lat' => '2.3711025426955', 'lng' => '99.0805054179688'], [
            'lat'  => 'required_with:lng|digits_between:1,15',
            'lng' => 'required_with:lat|digits_between:1,15',
          ]);
          dd($valid->fails());
```

which is **invalid**, it will work if we had the numbers without quotation marks. However, whatever input type of the input field to pass `lat` and `long` through html form. It regarded as string therefore invalid. I tried to `dd($request->all()` and the output are like:

```
array:2[
        "lat" => "2.3711025426955"
        "lng" => "99.0805054179688"
]
```

I pass it using forms like:

```
    <input type="text" name="lat">
    <input type="number" name="lat">
```

Both aren't working, it's rather bother some that i only works on backend but realize this problem messing around.
I am using **Laravel 5.1.26** anyway, hope someone shed some light on this - previously i'm pretty certain it works even with quotation marks.
Not sure, what's wrong but, [laravel uses php function `is_numeric`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L892) but somehow did not recognize my input (with quotation marks) as number.

**Edit** to clarify, i got this error:
`The lat must be between 1 and 15 digits.`
which is kind of weird, i'd say. To the weirdness `is_numeric('2.3711025426955')` is actually recognize my numbers correctly. Now i'm much more.. confused.

Comment: It could be a logic bug with Laravel's validation. Your string value is 16 in length due to the dot, it might be that validator is taking it into account. Can you try a different rule where 16 digits are allowed?

Comment: nope, still fails. **edit** well, now it works, idk why.

Comment: and yes, it actually [taking account of the dot](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L896). sorry for my stupidness - sorry to waste your time. i just careless reading the entire laravel internal validation code. thanks.

Comment: It's not stupidness, I would assume exactly the same thing as you have. I'm really glad you got it working, good luck with your project and have a nice day :)

Comment: thank you @Mjh i'm glad someone pointed the thing i missed out.

Comment: Use the `between` rule which is going to look at the value of the number itself rather than the length of it if it were converted to string.

Comment: ah, thanks for the idea. i just want to match the input and the space in database, the digits never more than 15 digits. i am not sure how the input value will looked like apart the number of digits - it's not an integer, so i can't make `between:1,99999..999`. the number of possible decimal place would be overwhelming.