# Laravel validation for a number which should be exactly 10 digits

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate a form which has phone number and we want that to be exactly 10 digits. But it gives errors even when the input is right I am using the following code in the controller so please advise as to what needs to be changed.

```
public function tytraining(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'txt_name'  => 'required',
            'txt_email' => 'required|email',
            'txt_phone' => 'required|numeric|between:9,11'
        ]);

        $name = Input::get('txt_name');

        $email = Input::get('txt_email');

        $phone = Input::get('txt_phone');

        $type = "bls-training";
        $url = '?' . Input::get('url');

        $medicalRequest = new ParseObject("MedicalRequest");

        $medicalRequest->set("name", $name);
        $medicalRequest->set("email", $email);
        $medicalRequest->set("phone", $phone);
        $medicalRequest->set("type", $type);
        $medicalRequest->set("requestMessage", "training");
        $medicalRequest->set("url", $url);

        try {
            $medicalRequest->save();

        } catch (ParseException $ex) {
            echo(' Some Error Occured');
        }
    }
```

Please advise how should I do the validation through Laravel..

Thank you all in advance for spending your valuable time and going through my concern and helping me out.

Comment: When you say "gives errors". What errors? Does it seem to fail the validation or is it an actual error?

Comment: You will not save mobile number as integer in database so if you are converting it to string then you can try it : `https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-size`

Answer (score 13):

use size and digits validation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-digits

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'txt_name'  => 'required',
            'txt_email' => 'required|email',
            'txt_phone' => 'required|digits:10'
        ]);
```

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2 and I don't see any validation by the name of digits here..

Comment: Yeah Sam it is there but it is not validating the number.. I have temporarlity used strlen() for validation and hoping for a better solution.

Comment: actually [in the background it uses `strlen`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1115), really. Even [i ever asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087356/send-number-using-html-form-to-laravel) why it always also count the dot on floating points, not only the numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't mentioned your Laravel version but since at least Laravel 4.2 you have [digits rule](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-digits) and this is what you need here, so your phone rule should look like this:

```
'txt_phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:10'
```

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2 and I don't see any validation by the name of digits here..

Comment: sorry digits validation is there but it is not working

Answer (score 5):

**For String length (Exact):**

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'input' => 'required|string|size:10'
        ];
```

**For digits length (Exact):**

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'input' => 'required|string|digits:10'
            ];
        }
```

**For String Range :**

```
   public function rules()
            {
                return [
                    'input' => 'required|string|min:5|max:10'
                ];
        }
```

**For digits Range :**

```
   public function rules()
            {
                return [
                    'input' => 'required|digits_between:5,10'
                ];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use this Validation to validate the Phone / Mobile Number between 9 - 11 or only 10 digits.

```
'txt_phone' => 'numeric|digits_between:9,11'
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are validating a string, You can use Laravel's [`'size:N'` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-size):

> For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an array, size corresponds to the count of the array. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

For example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required|string|size:32'
    ];
}
```